# padding and border are not working with tr tag

Tags: html, css

I need to give padding in my table and a bottom border for each row.
For this, I have created a class and using that class with tr tag.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#topLevel{
    background:powderblue;
    padding:30;
}
#container{
    background: white;
}

.row{
    background:white;
    padding: 10;
    border-bottom: 1pt solid black;

    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 12px;
    color : #979799;
    }

th {
    text-align: left;
}  
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="topLevel">
    <div id ="container">
    <table style="width:100%">
    <tr class = "row"> <th>CLAIM NO</th> <th>POLICY NO</th> <th>CLAIMANT NAME</th> <th>DATE OF INCIDENT </th> <th>REPORTED DATE</th> <th>CITY</th> <th>MOBILE NO</th> <th>ACTIONS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "row"> <td>CLAIM NO</td> <td>POLICY NO</td> <td>CLAIMANT NAME</td> <td>DATE OF INCIDENT </td> <td>REPORTED DATE</td> <td>CITY</td> <td>MOBILE NO</td> <td>ACTIONS</td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

 </html>
```

Please help

Comment: **10px** not **10** -- you need to specify the unit

Comment: Also border width properties have to be in "px".  You cannot use "pt".  "pt" only refers to fonts.

Comment: not working with even 10px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a table, you'd want to give the table border spacing:

```
table { 
  border-spacing:10px 10px;
}
```

**OR**

Give the table heads and table rows the padding:

```
tr.row th, tr.row td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to do the padding on the td element

```
    .row td {
        padding-top:10px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
    }

    .row td:first-child {
        padding-left:10px;
    }
    .row td:last-child {
        padding-right:10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to display as block, otherwise, it won't accept padding.

```css
#topLevel{
    background:powderblue;
    padding:30px;
}
#container{
    background: white;
}

.row{
    background:white;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display:block;
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 12px;
    color : #979799;
    }

th {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="topLevel">
    <div id ="container">
    <table style="width:100%">
    <tr class = "row"> <th>CLAIM NO</th> <th>POLICY NO</th> <th>CLAIMANT NAME</th> <th>DATE OF INCIDENT </th> <th>REPORTED DATE</th> <th>CITY</th> <th>MOBILE NO</th> <th>ACTIONS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "row"> <td>CLAIM NO</td> <td>POLICY NO</td> <td>CLAIMANT NAME</td> <td>DATE OF INCIDENT </td> <td>REPORTED DATE</td> <td>CITY</td> <td>MOBILE NO</td> <td>ACTIONS</td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

 </html>
```